# Reloaded file not change in java

Tags: java, image, swing, jfilechooser

Im try to load image with file chooser, 
but when I updated image after loaded, and reload it, image is not change. It just show first time loaded.
(I tryed not use filechooser)

Load-> change image -> Load -> image not change

Load-> change image ->Exit Program ->open program -> Load -> image change

How can I clear it?

Load Image

```
         int ret = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);    
         if(ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
             String filePath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
             ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(filePath);
             main.ChangeImage(icon);
         }
```

Change Image

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.drawImage(image.getImage(), 0, 0, this);

}

public void ChangeImage(ImageIcon img) {
    image = img;
    origin_image = image;
    origin_height = image.getIconHeight();
    origin_width = image.getIconWidth();

    this.setBounds(0, 0, image.getImage().getWidth(null), image.getImage()
            .getHeight(null));
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: `String filePath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
             ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(filePath);`  BTW - shorter would be `ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(chooser.getSelectedFile());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java tends to cache images.

If the images change during run-time, one way to fool the methods into reloading it is to read the bytes of the file yourself, form an input stream from them (using `ByteArrayInputStream`) and use the input stream in `ImageIO.read(InputStream)`.

The reason this works is that if an `URL` or `File` is used to load the image, the toolkit uses the location as a key to cache it.

---

### Other notes

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    // ..
```

Should be:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); // paint the border and BG to avoid arttifacts!
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    // ..
```